# Select2 - Works fine until using on Dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I'm wondering if anyone has uncounted this problem and know of a fix.

I'm using the excellent `select2` plugin which works flawlessly up to a point.

When I have select2 controls within a dialog, all works well until I close the dialog and re-open.  From then on, each time I click on a select2 control, the list quickly opens, then disappears.

Anyone know if this is a known problem or if there is a fix for this particular problem ?

*edit*

I'm calling the following `EACH` time the *dialog* is opening:

```
$("#cboValueAxis").select2({ allowClear: false, minimumResultsForSearch: 10 });
$("#cboValueAxis2").select2({ allowClear: false, minimumResultsForSearch: 10 });
```

*edit 2*
OK this is actually working fine on one condition, which is extremely strange.

If I have the `FireBug` debug panel open, I get the problem.  Closing the `Firebug` panel and it works flawlessly!

I'm wondering if there's some kind of z-ordering problem, but considering I've had zero problems before, it's very strange.

Have replicated the above using several browsers, only occurs in Firefox AND Firebug open!

Comment: please add your code. it might be a problem of including the script over and over again. or some other mistake. without the code we can't do much but predicting

Comment: Well I am setting the dropdown controls to a select2 each time the dialog is opening, should I only do it once?

Comment: it depends on your code? I haven't seen it, I can't judge :)

Comment: should show code relalted to opening/closing dialog and how you manage plugin within that code. Using `destroy` should help but also .what is the need to reinitialize in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

You have to destroy previous plugin before re-set it:

```
open:function(){
    $('#myselect').select2("destroy").select2();
}),
...
```

Or maybe better: (not sure it works as i dont know select2 plugin)

```
 open:function(){
        if(!$('#myselect').data('select2'))
             $('#myselect').select2();
    }),
```